# Inside the parent div i have two more elements. if i removed one then the rest of the element not aligning vertically center

Tags: html, css

Inside the parent element I have two more elements. If I removed one, then the rest of the element not aligning vertically center.

```css
h3 {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table;
  max-width: 115px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h3 a {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <a href="#">Nathan</a>
  <a href="#">sdfsdfsdf</a>
</h3>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate better?

Comment: where is the parent div in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `float:left;` as well as `display: table-cell;`. There is no point using it both. If you are making the `h3` to have a `display: table;`, then `display: table-cell;` is sufficient for you to get the float effect. You need to remove it to get what you are looking for.

**For Instance,**

```
h3 a {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uo0u9yev/)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left`. It doesn't work with `vertical-align`

```
h3{
text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #000;  
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table;
  max-width: 115px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
}

h3 a {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
```

HTML:

```
 <h3>
    <a href="#">Nathan</a>
    <!-- <a href="#">sdfsdfsdf</a> -->
 </h3>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8mdbfd7x/1/